# How to run some code before executing Spring web service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws

I implemented some rest web-services using spring.
I have some common code that I need to perform before every web service.
Crrently i explicitly call this common code at the start of each web service.

Is there a way to have spring "automatically" call this common code before calling web services?

Comment: Can you define 'before calling web services'?  Do you mean some configuration step (initialising a pool, loading/preparing resources and maps, building reference tables; etc.), or do you mean something that should be handled before every call to the service (authentication, audit logging, session initialisation, etc.)?

Comment: Have you tried any codes?! Can you post them for a clearer scenario?!

Comment: I need to save request information, (browser,ip and OS version) i need to access httpRequest object to do so, instead of do this manually with every webservice, i am asking if there is anything supported by spring to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using the spring aop intercept every web services,and execute the common code on it.Like following code:

```
<bean id="aspect" class="com.zhuyiren.Aspect"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="aspect">
        <aop:before method="before" pointcut="execution(* com.zhuyiren.service..*.*(..))"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

That above code means the invoke every method of some bean packaged at `com.zhuyiren.service` always execute the method `common` in `com.zhuyiren.Aspect`.You can write the common code in `common` method.Like:

```
public void common(){
    System.out.println("execute some common code");
}
```

The test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");
    UserService service = context.getBean(UserService.class);
    System.out.println(service.getUser(3));
}
```

The print is :

```
execute some common code
UserInfo{id=3, name='zhuyiren', password='123456', testString=[]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring have notion of interceptors - piece of code which "wraps" incoming requests
The simplest is to implement HandlerInterceptor interface:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class LetterzInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Next step is to register the interceptor with Spring:

```
    @Configuration
    public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

       @Override
       public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
           registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the code that you want to execute.

One technique is to use AOP (as described in the @dabaicai answer).

A different technique is to add a JEE filter to process the request before it lands in your handler method.

Here are some links:

1. [JEE6 Tutorial Filtering Requests and Responses](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)
2. [Oracle's Essentials of filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)
3. [Mkyong's Spring JEE filters](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/) - Take this with a grain of salt, Mkyong is light on explanation.

Another option: google search for "spring jee filter"